# PhaseScriptExecutionError when trying to run React Native app on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, ios-simulator

I'm getting an error when trying to run a react-native app on ios. Below is the error log. What I tried in order to fix it so far:

1. Delete derived data, Clean the project and run it on XCode
2. Delete the podfile.lock and run pod install

Would appreciate any help/pointers to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Error log:

Showing All Errors Only

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks
> /Users/dmuralidhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnrollMHC-bjohzknpvweosgggffnjlsixyoqs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMCore.build/Script-8B6871B03950171DCBE26E07AA21B95D.sh
> (in target 'UMCore' from project 'Pods')
> cd /Users/dmuralidhar/Documents/RN_POC/EnrollMHC/ios/Pods
> /bin/sh -c /Users/dmuralidhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnrollMHC-bjohzknpvweosgggffnjlsixyoqs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMCore.build/Script-8B6871B03950171DCBE26E07AA21B95D.sh
> Selected xcframework slice ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator rsync --delete
> -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" "/Users/dmuralidhar/Documents/RN_POC/EnrollMHC/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios/UMCore.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/*"
> "/Users/dmuralidhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EnrollMHC-bjohzknpvweosgggffnjlsixyoqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMCore"
> building file list ... rsync: link_stat
> "/Users/dmuralidhar/Documents/RN_POC/EnrollMHC/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios/UMCore.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator//*"
> failed: No such file or directory (2) done sent 29 bytes  received 20
> bytes  98.00 bytes/sec total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 rsync error:
> some files could not be transferred (code 23) at
> /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/38cf1d983f/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(996)
> [sender=2.6.9] Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit
> code

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the following code:

- Go to 'node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh'.
- Comment out the whole find-node.sh file.
- Rebuild your project